# How to say "gibberish" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I have been on multiple sentence bases and have found words such as 胡言乱语，词不达意。。。But is there another, better term?

Comment: Better in what sense?  The examples you give are great for what they say.

Comment: Right like Colin said, what's the context?

Comment: what is a sentence base？ Anyhow online dictionaries 
contain many more possible translations with example sentences。（iciba e。g。has ５ to begin with，all different from the ２ in above question）

Comment: I heard 鸟语 used before to refer to "unintelligible language", but it depends on the context as said by the fellows here above.

Comment: I think 胡言乱语 is a very good translation. You need a context to suggest better translations for that particular context.

Answer (score 1):

胡说八道 hu2 shuo1 ba1 dao4

This is a 四字词 which means to talk rubbish.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Chinese Language SE. Nice answer!

Comment: `胡说八道` is used for `nonsense`/`lie` more.

Answer (score 0):

if I do this translation, I would say 一派胡言